# After shifting an array This condition will always evaluate to false

Tags: typescript

I'm writing some code for work, and am having an issue with typescript not realizing that I've changed the array.

```
function example() {
  const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  switch (arr[0]) {
    case 1:
      arr.shift();
      if (arr[0] === 2) {// Typescript complains that this will always evaluate to false
        console.log(2);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

I know that I can get around this by casting `arr[0]` as a number, but is there any other way to inform typescript that I've modified the array?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've googled a bit before posting here and couldn't find any relevant discussion.

Comment: Why your array is marked `const` if you want to modify it?

Comment: @AterLux - `const` refers to the binding, not the object the binding refers to. It means we can't change what's in `arr` (for instance, by making it refer to a different array).

Comment: seems a bug to me.

Comment: Whoops, mistyped. Typescript says it will always evaluate to false, because it thinks that arr[0] is still 0 from the switch case. I will edit the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seams like you found a bug !

The assumption the compiler make is true without the the `shift` because `arr[0]` is narrowed to `1` thanks to the switch case.

But since `shift()` changes the array in place, the compiler is making a wrong assumption here.

```
function example() {
  const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  switch (arr[0]) {
    case 1:
      arr.shift();
      const two = arr[0]; // 
        //  ^? '1'
      console.log(two); // 2
      break;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgEpEBvAKEUQgQGcpF0AnJxAXkQG0BGAGgCZeAZl4AWXgFZeANl4B2ALoBuSoloB3GFAgALRAWZNOABgUkKVKhHS1kibgC5VlxiwB0tHTGBRiKl1Z0DFDqcOyuRqb%20AVQA9LFUAHoA-M6WNGC0cPhuuHAA5gQhcERKiPGI-GlU1YgARkzI6ADW0QC%205B3kaFh4hERAA)

---

Yup, it's a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) (pointed by [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48204) closed as duplicate)

Comment: The issue makes it seem that is should be considered a *design limitation* and not a bug.

Comment: It's both a design limitation and a bug. The typing is definitely wrong here.

Comment: I would note that one should definitely not expect a fix for this anytime soon (or ever)

Comment: @TobiasS. yeah we should definitely not expect a fix soon.